AWS Lambda Function using Docker image with module not found error
I have a simple node.js application running puppeteer to extract and process reports from a website.
I had some compatibility issues with chromium and lambda so I decided to contain the application in a Docker container. Here is my Dockerfile :
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/nodejs:18

# Install dependencies
RUN yum install -y \
    fontconfig \
    freetype \
    git \
    bzip2 \
    && yum clean all \
    && rm -rf /var/cache/yum

# Copy package.json and package-lock.json files to the /app directory in the container
COPY package*.json ./

# Install production dependencies, including puppeteer-core and chrome-aws-lambda
RUN npm install chrome-aws-lambda puppeteer-core && \
    npm install

# Copy the rest of the application code to the /app directory
COPY ./src ./src
COPY ./handler.js ./handler.js

# Set the command to run the Lambda function handler
CMD ["handler.handler"]

I built and ran the image locally and everything works perfectly. I then pushed to AWS ECR and created a Lambda Function using the pushed image.
When I test the lambda function with a valid event, I always get this error :
{
  "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
  "errorMessage": "Error: Cannot find module 'liveiq'\nRequire stack:\n- /var/runtime/index.mjs",
  "trace": [
    "Runtime.ImportModuleError: Error: Cannot find module 'liveiq'",
    "Require stack:",
    "- /var/runtime/index.mjs",
    "    at _loadUserApp (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1087:17)",
    "    at async UserFunction.js.module.exports.load (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1119:21)",
    "    at async start (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1282:23)",
    "    at async file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1288:1"
  ]
}

My handler.js is file located at the root of my project and the rest of the code is in the /src directory. Here is my handler.js file :
('use strict');

const { getEmployees, putEmployees, getReportingData } = require('./src/liveiq.js');

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
  // Log the event for debugging purposes
  const { functionName, startDate, endDate } = event;
  console.log('Current working directory:', process.cwd());

  if (functionName === 'getEmployees') {
    return await getEmployees();
  } else if (functionName === 'putEmployees') {
    return await putEmployees(event);
  } else if (functionName === 'getReporting') {
    return await getReportingData(startDate, endDate);
  } else {
    throw new Error('Function not found');
  }
};

I tried multiple variations of Dockerfile
I tried to override the CWD and the CMD in AWS Lambda
I pulled and ran the image from aws ecr and all the files were properly copied in /var/task
I am running out of ideas ...

"I built and ran the image locally and everything works perfectly. " how did you invoke the image locally?  My bet would be on an unexpected current working directory.  You could output the current working directory before attempting to import from ./src

The Cannot find module x error is usually caused by:

Invalid path to a file
Bad file name
Missing file

Without the folder structure there isn't much context to dig deeper.
You could run the container locally using Docker Daemon and inspect the folder structure from there and check if it matches with the 'non-Docker' structure
